# Fastlane failed to receive a connection from the FastlaneRunner binary after 5 seconds

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, fastlane

After a rough day for our CI, when we finally got it back online `fastlane` starting failing builds immediately with the message:

```
fastlane failed to receive a connection from the FastlaneRunner binary after 5 seconds
```

Due to COVID-19 we are all WFH so ideally don't want to shut down the build slave in case we can't get it back online.

How can we get our builds working again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12604) gave me a tip off that Fastlane might be running somewhere else. I then found that there were indeed some stale Fastlane processes on the slave:

```
$ ps -A | grep -i fastlane
30090 ??         0:11.04 ruby /Users/<redacted>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/fastlane test --verbose    
30154 ttys000    0:00.01 sh -c set -o pipefail && env NSUnbufferedIO=YES xcodebuild -workspace ./<redacted>.xcworkspace -scheme <redacted>_iOS\ Prod -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=52D9686C-79BB-4D98-8A05-FDF3FB659BA5' -derivedDataPath '/Users/<redacted>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<redacted>-cftrijcalkbyledyzrsthsbefqmz' build test | tee '/Users/<redacted>/Library/Logs/scan/<redacted>_iOS-<redacted>_iOS Prod.log' | xcpretty  --report html --output '/Users/<redacted>/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/<redacted>/fastlane/test_output/report.html' --report junit --output '/Users/<redacted>/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/<redacted>/fastlane/test_output/report.junit' --report junit --output '/var/folders/0m/v5x0gd316qn4msj39z81_yym0000gp/T/junit_report20200319-30090-b9dtoq' 
30157 ttys000    0:05.37 /Users/<redacted>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby /Users/<redacted>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/xcpretty --report html --output /Users/<redacted>/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/<redacted>/fastlane/test_output/report.html --report junit --output /Users/<redacted>/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/<redacted>/fastlane/test_output/report.junit --report junit --output /var/folders/0m/v5x0gd316qn4msj39z81_yym0000gp/T/junit_report20200319-30090-b9dtoq
65854 ttys001    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn -i fastlane
65139 ttys002    0:00.00 sh -c ./fastlane/FastlaneRunner lane test logMode verbose swiftServerPort 2000 > /dev/null
65140 ttys002    0:00.10 ./fastlane/FastlaneRunner lane test logMode verbose swiftServerPort 2000
65507 ttys002    0:00.00 sh -c ./fastlane/FastlaneRunner lane test logMode verbose swiftServerPort 2000 > /dev/null
65508 ttys002    0:00.06 ./fastlane/FastlaneRunner lane test logMode verbose swiftServerPort 2000
```

I then `kill -9`-ed all the processes, e.g.

```
kill -9 30154
```

After that, the CI started building properly!